# data table not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using this code to display the table.

```
tablacambios = $('#tablacambios').dataTable( {
                    "bJQueryUI": true,  
                    "sScrollY": "150px",
                    "bPaginate": false
                } )
```

but when the table has few records are not displayed correctly. the footer is shown below.

I put a screenshot [here](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-datatable-8043680.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this to your options:

```
"bScrollCollapse": true,
```